# How to change the icons for tables displayed in Power BI Desktop field list?

Tags: powerbi

I can see that some tables have different icons, and I would like to be able to decide which icons is associated to a table.

I have tried creating an empty table with just measures in it, but the icon stays the same as for regular tables. I cannot figure out why the first table called "Totals" in my example of tabular model gets a different icon in Power BI Desktop field list.

I would like to find out how Power BI Desktop decides to assign which icon to a table.

See screenshot, the green arrow is pointing to an icon that is different from all the other tables in the model.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make any table look like the one you have on the top:

- Hide all columns in a table (right-click a field, select "Hide");
- Once all columns are hidden, save pbix file, close, re-open.

Essentially, the icon changes when a table contains no visible data fields, but has DAX measures. Designers often use this trick to organize their measures in one place, instead of assigning them to many different tables.